# $array[$key] returns null

Tags: php

Can anyone have a quick look at my array?

I don't understand what the hell is going on.

Here's `var_dump($result)`

```
array(24) {
  ... had to remove some code
  ["fuel"]=>
  string(8) "Gasoline"
  ["type"]=>
  string(13) "Full-size Van"
  ["internetPrice"]=>
  string(4) "9988"
  ["listing title"]=>
  string(53) "2008 Ford Econoline E350 Super Duty One Owner Box Van"
  ["Car URL"]=>
  string(67) "http://www.familytrucksandvans.com/vehicle.cfm?vehicleID=220459648
"
}
```

`$result['Car URL']` returns `NULL` (that's the last value), even though it's present.

all other values work (`$result['listing title']` etc)

Comment: Can you show code that you're trying to access `$result['Car URL']` and anything between the initialization (or where you dumped the above) and that access point?

Comment: Don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you please post your full PHP code ? Or the part using $result['Car URL'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = array('Car URL'=> 'http://www.blablabla.com',
        'listing title' => '2008 Ford Mondeo');

print $array['Car URL'];


redi$ php test.php 
http://www.blablabla.com
```

There is not obvious reason why it should not work from what you are showing here .

My wild guess would be any typo error

Answer (score 0):

'Car URL' had `\r` and `\n` symbols in the end.